# Perl return object in command line

Tags: perl, cmd

In my code I load database files then use them several times.

Is there anyway to return an object in Perl using the command line then reuse it in another command?

For example:

```
perl -Mpckg -e '$v = pckg::foo();'
perl -Mpckg2 -e 'pckg2::foo(&v);'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but you have to use temporary file for keeping an object.

`perl -MStorable -Mpckg -e '$v=pckg::foo(); Storable::store(\$v,file)'`

your object $v will be written in file after that you have to run this:

`perl -MStorable -Mpckg2 -e '$v = Storable::retrieve(file); unlink file; pckg2::foo($v)`

So you may give your defined object to pckg2::foo() function and your temporary file will be deleted after that. That's all.

Comment: I tried your code returning a string from pckg::foo() but that's what I got SCALAR(0x89b5f10). How can I get the value of the object ?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what 'value of the object' means but I guess you have to try use `pckg2::foo($$v)`

Comment: yes I meant the value of the string not the reference. Thanks that worked.

Comment: I can't think of a when this solution would be a good idea. There are better ways to store data.

Comment: @ikegami give us some examples or which module is needed use for this, please.

Comment: I did not try it, but im sure that open db connections and open file handles can survive this.

Answer (score 3):

This can not work. There are several reasons. One is that your first perl process is gone when you start the second one. By the way you can not use references this way.

Comment: Is there no way to work around this? I am calling perl commands from Java that's why I am using system calls

Comment: No. I don't think that you can do it this way.

Comment: But what are you doing? What do you do in Java and what in Perl? And why? May be we find an other solution for your problem.

Comment: Actually I am using a tool already written in perl and another written in Java that's why I have to merge between them. I just wanted to decrease the runtime of the perl command.

Comment: Then you should join your perl scripts together. That reduces the time loading the interpreter.

Comment: Or post your scripts in a new question. "how to improve the performance of my Perl scripts."

Answer (score 3):

No, one process cannot access the memory of another process, especially one that's not even running anymore, much less safely use its variables.

You're probably looking to make a server of the first script. Rather than exiting, it would stay running and accept commands (say, via STDIN from its parent, or via a socket from any process) that it would parse and execute using the object it constructed when it first started.

Comment: I think his intention is to have some kind of persistence between 2 calls and probably it's more appropiate to use something involving Storable and a temporary file, but of course things become more complicated compared to what he provided as an example